# A pair of number squares

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Given these squares of numbers (maybe you can even solve it with just one!):

```
 9   6   2
 8   x   7
 7   7   1
```

> ```
>  11   9   7
>   7   x   6
>  12   4   3
> ```

What is the value of x?

While the accepted answer is correct, the reasoning is actually a bit more involved:

> All calculations are in the field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$. 
>  The first two numbers in each row sum to the third. 
>  The first two numbers in each column multiply to the third

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  value of **x** is  :

> 12 for both puzzle

Reasoning(for first puzzle) :

> For first puzzle :
>
> ```
> 9   6   2
>  8   x   7
>  7   7   1
> ```
>
> ```
> In first row in we need to add first two columns number and then subtract 13 to get the number in last column .i.e:
>  for first row : 9+6=15-13=2
>  for third row : 7+7=14-13=1
>  for second row : 8+x-13=7 ( let ? be x )
>                    -5+x=7 => x=7+5=> x=12
> ```

Reasoning(for second puzzle) :

> For second puzzle :
>
> ```
>  11   9   7
>   7   x   6
>  12   4   3
> ```
>
> ```
> In first row in we need to add first two columns number and then subtract 13 to get the number in last column .i.e:
>  for first row : 11+9=20-13=7
>  for third row : 12+4=16-13=3
>  for second row : 7+x-13=6 ( let ? be x )
>                    -6+x=6 => x=6+6 => x=12
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure here but my pattern seems to work.
The value of x is

> 1 in both squares.

Explanation :

> ```
> in the following square :
> a b c
> d e f
> g h i
> we have a=h+c and g=b+i.
> notice we are adding numbers on the 2nd and 3rd columns to get the number in the first column.
> Since d, e and f were the only unused number, we can assume d=e+f
> Therefore, 8=x+7 and 7=x+6
> ```

I might have entirely missed the pattern and found a wrong answer, but this is the best I could come up with.